# JSP Date to PostgreSQL Date JasperException

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql

This is the second week trying to find an answer to my problem... everything fine works except when inserting a date field to database  problem... I am sure someone can help me!   THANK YOU !

Database column is: campstart and it is a "Timestamp without time zone"

++++++++++ JSP page with the following:

... (some code)  // Formatting the date:

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");`

... (some code)   // getting input from webpage

```
<input name="start" type="text" value="<%= defaultCampaign.getCampstart() != null ? dateFormat.format(defaultCampaign.getCampstart()) : dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date()) %>">
```

... (more code)

++++++++++ On Java:

... (some code)   // declaring variable

`private java.util.Date campstart = null;`

... (some code)   // assigning data

```
public void setCampstart(java.util.Date aCampstart) {   
this.campstart = aCampstart;  } 

public java.util.Date getCampstart() {
  return this.campstart; }
```

... (some code)  // writing to PostgreSQL +below is the line with problems+

```
pst.setTimestamp(10, new Timestamp(this.getCampstart().getTime()));
```

... (more code)

+++++++++

It works fine when I change the code line to the following (for debugging):

`pst.setTimestamp(10, new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));`

The date Insert works perfectly, it writes to Database without errors.  But, when I change the code to insert the user date, it gives me the following error:

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "04/07/2012 19:12" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "campstart": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager*

Can someone please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong...

THANK YOU !!

Rob.

Comment: What object is this.getCampstart().getTime() returning? Is it a date or a string?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628390/411902

Comment: It seems that is bringing a null.. It is supposed to get a date entered by a user from the JSP page.  I just can not pin-point the problem... (all other fields work fine, except the date).  

I am not sure if its java.util.Date to java.sql.Date conversion issue, or it is not passing the date from JSP page to the Java class; or the format is incorrect... but tried different settings, and just can not crack it !!  :(

Comment: Rob, if I change the setters to String then the Date inputs on JSP page will not work (I also have a pop calendar that brings the date with the correct format). 'SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")'

Comment: Got it to work when I changed the format on the date. For some reason it was sending it on the month like "7" instead of "07".  Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work when I changed the format on the date. For some reason it was sending it on the month like "7" instead of "07".